# Create dummy string and return error message if true

Tags: java, webobjects

I need to create a dummy string for my application on when a user search for an existing mail and if it is tagged as "erased" it will return an error message "user erased"

here is my wod file.

**WOD:**

```
<WebObject name=form2>

Customer email address:

<WebObject name=emailField></WebObject>

<WebObject name=submitEmailButton></WebObject>

</WebObject>

submitEmailButton : WOSubmitButton {
    action = submitEmail;
    value = "Search";
}
```

**java:**

```
NSArray persons = Person.personsWithEmail(email, session().defaultEditingContext());
        if ( (persons == null) || (persons.count() == 0) ) {
            errorMessage = "customer email \"" + email + "\" could not be found.";
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: So, what's the problem you have? Questions are encouraged to provide a [Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), try to [improve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) yours.

Comment: Here's how you create a dummy string, use this line of code:  String dummy = "dummy";

Comment: What does the method submitEmail do?

Comment: What does the WOD look like for: emailField:

Comment: this is how submitemail look like in wod.

<WebObject name=form2>
Customer email address: <WebObject name=emailField></WebObject>
<WebObject name=submitEmailButton></WebObject>
</WebObject>

<br>
submitEmailButton : WOSubmitButton {
    action = submitEmail;
    value = "Search";
I need to add a condition that will check once a flag is tagged as erased it will show the error message.

Answer (score 0):

this is how submitemail look like in wod.

```
<WebObject name=form2>
Customer email address: <WebObject name=emailField></WebObject>
<WebObject name=submitEmailButton></WebObject>
</WebObject>

<br>
submitEmailButton : WOSubmitButton {
    action = submitEmail;
    value = "Search";
```

I need to add a condition that will check once a flag is tagged as erased it will show the error message.